# how intercept requests with webservicehost

Tags: wcf

I am using WebServiceHost in a commandline app. I want to do the equivalent of this snippet that I got from a web application. Any ideas ?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
}

private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Like this.

http://dhvik.blogspot.com/2011/06/supporting-cross-origin-resource_9123.html

Comment: Would you like to add an excerpt of that page to your post? That way, your answer will remain useful if the link dies.